# PDO exception in JOIN query

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

I've been on this all morning and I can't figure out why it's not working.

```
$spn = '20275096';
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; Dbq=".realpath('exported/test1.mdb')."; Uid=Admin");   
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(" SELECT Cup_PartUpdateCommodityID FROM Cup_PartUpdateCommodity 
                   INNER JOIN Cup_PartUpdateInfo ON 
                      [Cup_PartUpdateCommodity].Cup_PartUpdateCommodityID = [Cup_PartUpdateInfo].Cup_PartUpdateCommodityID 
                   INNER JOIN Cup_PartUpdate ON 
                      [Cup_PartUpdateInfo].Cup_PartUpdateID = [Cup_PartUpdate].Cup_PartUpdateID 
                   WHERE [Cup_PartUpdate].PartNum = :partnum ");

$stmt->bindParam(':partnum', $spn);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(); 
echo $row['Cup_PartUpdateCommodityID'];
```

It throws the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
> 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: -3100
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing
> operator) in query expression
> '[Cup_PartUpdateCommodity].Cup_PartUpdateCommodityID =
> [Cup_PartUpdateInfo].Cup_PartUpdateCommodityID INNER JOIN
> Cup_PartUpdate ON [Cup_PartUpdateInfo].Cup_PartUpdateID =
> [Cup_PartUpdate].Cup_PartUpdateID'. (SQLExecute[-3100] at
> ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254)' in C:\sites\myproject\test.php:31
>
> Stack
> trace: #0 C:\sites\myproject\test.php(31): PDOStatement->execute() #1
> {main} thrown in C:\sites\myproject\test.php on line 31

Note: The code above will be executed in a function that expects $spn as a parameter. Just for now I'm setting a default value for $spn. Anyone?

Comment: I know Access does some things in unexpected ways - do you need the square brackets around the tablenames? I'd suggest taking them out if they're not required.

Comment: I've tried the both ways, same result.

Comment: It was worth a try. In that case, can you try simplifying the statement while you debug? Leave in one of the INNER JOINs and remove the other, and see if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution based on [this](http://www.justskins.com/forums/microsoft-odbc-microsoft-access-149201.html#post501600).

It turns out that JOINS for MS Access need to be done like this:

```
A JOIN (
B JOIN C ON <condition_BC>
) ON <condition_AB>
```

instead of like the MySQL way:

```
A JOIN B ON <condition_AB>
JOIN C ON <condition_BC>
```

So finally my query looks like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; Dbq=".realpath('exported/test1.mdb')."; Uid=Admin");   
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare(" SELECT * FROM Cup_PartUpdateCommodity 
                            LEFT JOIN (
                              Cup_PartUpdateInfo LEFT JOIN Cup_PartUpdate ON Cup_PartUpdateInfo.Cup_PartUpdateID = Cup_PartUpdate.Cup_PartUpdateID 
                            ) ON Cup_PartUpdateCommodity.Cup_PartUpdateCommodityID = Cup_PartUpdateInfo.Cup_PartUpdateCommodityID
                            WHERE Cup_PartUpdate.PartNum = :partnum ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':partnum', $spn);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    echo $row['Cup_PartUpdateCommodityID'];
```